# Redux: Missing semicolon; Getting weird syntax error

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux, frontend

It's my first time using Redux and for practice purposes, I am trying to build something like a Book Library where you can add, search for, edit, delete books. I'm trying to create an action but it gives me a weird error "Missing semicolon". I come from Python if that helps.

This is an action from my code:

```
export const AddBook = (title, ratings, synopsis) => {
    type: BOOK_ADDED,
    payload: {
        title,
        ratings,
        synopsis
    }
};
```

The error is at "payload". Here is a picture of the error to help explain it:
[image]

This is what it shows me when I try to compile it:
[image]

Comment: If you want to do an implicit return of an object from a function, you need to wrap it inside parenthesis, like so `const AddBook = (title, ratings, synapsis) => ({ payload: {} })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
export const AddBook = (title, ratings, synopsis) => {
  return {
    type: BOOK_ADDED,
    payload: {
        title,
        ratings,
        synopsis
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, both this and @goto1 's solution has worked.

Comment: Yep `()` in the arrow function does the same thing as this, implicit return